# Does the liquid effect in these photographs have a specific name?

Tags: terminology, fashion

I aspire to become a fashion and wildlife photographer, and I am starting out in that mission today. Lucky me, and the first photographer whose works I came across is Jaroslav Wieczorkiewicz.

His photography involves (splashed) liquids dressing the models, stunning I must say. What an inspiration to start with. (And moreover, it doesn't involve photo-editing for the effects.) But I don't know what to call this.

Different terms were used, like "Water Angel", "Water illustration", or "Milk Illustration" (if milk is used), and etc. — but does this kind of photography have a specific name?

Examples:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALKhA.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZLlx.jpg

source: http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaroslav/sets/72157626124758315/

Comment: I wouldn't post the images directly here because you do now own the images either, I think the links are fine.

Comment: @dpollitt okay...

Comment: Jarek, the photographer, says this is a technique (capturing liquids frozen in mid-air), not a genre, according to this behind-the-scenes story published last week on Strobist: http://strobist.blogspot.com/2011/10/backsplash-on-budget-jaroslav.html

Comment: Yeah, that is how I came to know Jaroslav Wieczorkiewicz's works. I thought that's some kind of photography like wild-life photography, outdoor photography etc. Get it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Fashion For Walls

Similar photos have been done before such as by the ad agency TBWA for the "Fashion for Walls" campaign. In this case they used a combination of a real model, and a mannequin was switched out, and then they threw paint buckets at the mannequin. Then in post production the two were combined.

I wouldn't say that these photos don't "involve photo-editing for the effects" rather, they don't use computer generated imagery for the effect, they just post process multiple images together.

### Milk & Water

For Jaroslav Wieczorkiewicz's work, details can be found at this [stobist post here](http://strobist.blogspot.com/2011/10/backsplash-on-budget-jaroslav.html). The main idea is that he used very high speed capture to freeze the water on the black background.

Jaroslav points out that the most important aspect is the concept, beyond that the actual work of putting it all together is not as difficult.

I have not attended one of his workshops where he gives detailed step by step instructions on how to accomplish works such as MILK. From what I can tell his work is a composite of many water/milk thrown images and images that are of the models by themselves on black studio backgrounds. Mix that with very high speed shots and ultra fast strobes/lights and you have the main idea.

Information directly from Jaroslav on the "Playing with water shoot": [Here](http://aurumlight.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/playing-with-water-the-silver-angel/)

Fashion for Walls info: [Here](http://www.ilovebelgium.be/a-splash-of-paint)

Comment: Does this kind of photography have a name? (did I miss it?) Is it called "Fashion for Walls" photography?

Comment: Jaroslav calls it "Water Illustration". Fashion for walls is a brand of paint. I would call either of the examples, fashion photography.

Comment: I am trying to do this too and confused with "speed" : Does it mean I should go to as high as I can with sync speed? I can go to 1/8000 . OR does it mean I can stay at like 1/500 and what they really mean is "flash duration" and if I am correct that is built-in and I can't change it right? I have a Profoto B1s

Comment: @Blake - See the link I shared. "a mind blowing flash duration 1/13,500 of a second (t.1)!". Its not only shutter speed but also flash duration. I'm skeptical that your shutter *sync* speed is 1/8000. Maybe if you have a leaf shutter.